# In Git how can you check which repo in Github you are pushing to from the command line?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have several projects I am working on. I am constantly pulling and pushing. Recently I made some changes to one of my files, added and committed and decided to push my project A, however it pushed into my Github Project B. I then did git pull for kicks and it this happened.

- branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
  Already up-to-date.

It did not pull none of my files from Project B. I then did git status and it showed every single file/folders in my directory as needing to be committed. How would I know which "init" I am on? How can I switch out of this state and how can I disregard these blind commits without losing my files?

Comment: Keep in mind that in the *worst* case, you can always clone a new repo from the correct location and the just drop all your current files into it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think you need to reconfig git `remote`

type `git remote -v` and see if there's a mismatch or not.
If there is, follow this instruction from github: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Comment: Just In Time  answer!

Answer (score 28):

You can check the configs of your repository by :

```
git config -l
```

which contains your remote repository url.

Also, you can use the following command :

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: if I run `git config -l` it does not show me the remote url just a lot of the settings (user.name, user.email etc.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the name type

1. git remote -v
2. git remote rename OLDNAME NEWNAME

If it doesnt accept commits after this. You can try

git pull NEWNAME main

git push NEWNAME main

Comment: While this information is correct, I don't think it addresses the question asked here.